# How to make my Object Image within my S3 Bucket Public in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set my Object I have in my S3 Bucket to Public which I can do manually by selecting 'Make Public' option which allows 'Read' access within the Object ACL which works fine since it displays the image on my webpage fine, my question is what python code would I have to use to allow this 'Read' access within the ACL to allow my image to be public?

I have tried generating a policy which didn't work, I set the whole bucket to public which still didn't allow the image to be public aswell. So unsure what Python code would allow this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'eu-west-1')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
keyname = 'key2.pem'
user_data = '''#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd'''
s3.create_bucket(ACL='private',Bucket='ec2-buket1',CreateBucketConfiguration={'$
sg = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='webServer', Description = 'WebServer'$


response = sg.authorize_ingress(
    IpPermissions=[
        {
            "FromPort": 22,
            "ToPort": 22,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "WebServer"},
            ],
        },
        {
            "FromPort": 80,
            "ToPort": 80,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "WebServer"},
            ],
        },
    ],
)

instance = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-64ecf1b725342da',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.nano',
 KeyName = 'key2.pem',
 UserData = user_data, 
 SecurityGroupIds=[sg.group_id] 
)
for bucket_name in sys.argv[1:]:
 try:
         response = s3.create_bucket(Bucket=ec2-assignbuke2,
CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'})
         print (response)
 except Exception as error:
         print (error)

def upload_to_s3(filename, bucket, key):
  try:
    response = s3.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=open(filename, 'lr'))
    print (response)
    return response
  except Exception as error:
    print (error)

file = 'image1.jpg'
bkt = 'ec2-bucket1'
key = 'image1.jpg'
rsp = upload_to_s3(file, bkt, key)

object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('bucket2','image1.jpg')

response = object_acl.put(
    ACL='public-read',
    AccessControlPolicy={
        'Grants': [
            {
                'Grantee': {
                    'BucketName': 'bucket2',
                    'Key' : 'image1.jpg'
                },
                'Permission': 'READ'
            },
        ],
     }
    GrantRead='string',
    GrantReadACP='string',
    VersionId='string',
)
```

Comment: Can you please show any code you tried with error messages?

Comment: Well when I run my script it just creates the S3 bucket with the image inside without any errors but I am trying to figure out what I need to do to make the image within public via python code without manually making it public each time. I can't find any solutions online when I had a look.

Comment: Which script? You haven't showed any.

Comment: where is your code? And yes, we need more input. We need all your input because we can't read in your mind.

Comment: I have updated it but I asked because I thought my explanation of what I wanted to happen was clear enough that there would be just a code on boto3 site that allows you to set S3 bucket objects ACL to Read access.

Comment: In a similar way to how you've created an S3 Object, you can also create an S3 [ObjectAcl](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectacl), then modify its grant, then [put](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ObjectAcl.put) it.

Comment: I've uploaded the code to what you mentioned, I found a object_acl.put in relation to a email address so I modified it a bit to what I thought it would be for an S3 bucket but I am getting an error for GrantRead='String'

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach would be to specify the ACL as part of the upload:

```py
s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_file(filename, key, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

Comment: Gives me an error of s3_resource is not defined? Also what is the 'key' value supposed to be linked too as I just have the file name down for it.

Comment: Never mind, I had to call it to the boto3.resource('s3') and had to write it as 'filename', 'key' instead of it normally as you had, all works fine now!